# Javascript to replace a string inside a tag

Tags: javascript, replace

```
<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb"><a href="http://domain.com/" class="home">Home</a> &gt; Product</nav>
```

Using jQuery or Javascript how would I be able to rename the word 'Product' to some other value?

```
var brandname = $('.tax-product_brand h1.page-title').text();
var crumb = $('.woocommerce-breadcrumb').text();
console.log(crumb);
crumb.replace("Product", brandname);
```

I tried the above with no luck

Answer (score 3):

You then need to insert your string into the DOM. As it is, you're just doing a string operation and discarding the return value.

```
$('.woocommerce-breadcrumb').text(crumb.replace("Product", brandname));
```

EDIT: As mentioned in a comment, you should use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. `.text()` will strip all of your HTML, i.e. your `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.html()` rather than `.text()` or else you'll lose your markup:

```
var crumb = $('.woocommerce-breadcrumb').html();
```

Then apply the value back to the element:

```
$('.woocommerce-breadcrumb').html(crumb.replace("Product", brandname));
```

---

Alternatively, a much easier way would be to put "Product" in its own element, and then just replace that element's text:

```
<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb"><a href="http://domain.com/" class="home">Home</a> &gt; <span class="item">Product</span></nav>
```

Then your jQuery would simply be:

```
$(".woocommerce-breadcrumb .item").text(brandname);
```

Comment: Cleanest solution, better for further development.

Answer (score 0):

`.replace` returns a new string, so you have to set the text of `crumb` with the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

Its replaced Here is demo.

`var brandname = 'My Name';`

`var crumb = 'My Product';`

`console.log(crumb);`

`var d= crumb.replace("Product", brandname);`

`alert(d);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var brandname = $('.tax-product_brand h1.page-title').text();
$(".woocommerce-breadcrumb:contains('Product')").html(function(_, html) {
    return  html.replace(/(Product)/g, '<span>'+brandname+'</span>')
});
```

I was able to use the above to gain what I wanted whilst keeping the formatting of the a tag

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using free text. This will increase processing overhead, when you'll do DOM calculations.

It is good, if you can use  tag to display the end product/page name.
The html will look like:

```
  <nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb">
        <a href="http://domain.com/" class="home">
            Home
        </a> 
        <span class="currentPage">>Product</span>

    </nav>
```

Now, you can use simple DOM operation to change the text() of expected element.

```
var currentPage=$(".currentPage");
$(currentPage).text('> NewText');
```